# Put every initial variable in Node serializer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, variables, redux

I have a React app through which users can register an account. When registering, I want to set certain variables, so when they visit certain sections of the app they will display things or not. E.g.: When the user visits the To-do component he will have an initial of 0 todos saved. If he adds any, those will be added to his account via POST method (express).

Question: DO I have to add all those variables I want via the Schema and serialize functions? I am pretty sure I don't want to just host those variables in the redux store, but rather pull them from the backend since they will be different for each user.

E.g.:

```
UserSchema.methods.serialize = function() {
  return {
    username: this.username || "",
    firstName: this.firstName || "",
    lastName: this.lastName || "",
    toDos: this.toDos,
    readTOS: this.readTOS,
    etc.
  };
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean regarding the redux store--how is that not per-user? It's on the client. Regardless, where are you pulling the user from now if not the back end? I also probably wouldn't keep that directly in the user but rather some associated user metadata, but that's a relatively minor point/change.

Comment: @DaveNewton I can either initialize those variables via the component and then POST them to the backend, or save writing the initialState and directly initialize these variables when the user registers. I am pulling the user from the backend. I read that one shouldn't create big states, and rather handle variables via the backend directly

Comment: State should contain whatever you need to do what you need to do on the client side. If the client needs to know if the user has read the TOS, and that information exists on the back end, then anything you do on the client side is pointless, the back end drives it. Maybe I'm misunderstand what you're asking, but so far, it doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Comment: Let me reformulate the question. When the user registers his account I want to initialize ALL the variables needed on the backen to perform all the actions on the client side. How do i tie the UserSchema into all the other variables like readTOS, etc. ?

Comment: You should not allow the client side to initialize variables outside of their control: those are back-end concerns; the only thing the client can do is tell the back end what they've done that might affect them. Think of it this way: if you had an `admin` flag would you let the user craft a request that could turn it on so that they could grant themselves admin access? (Hint: no.)